# Is posting any exception in a question a declarative statement to resolve it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I had an argument with a fellow member about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834914/classnotfoundexception-exception-while-converting-html-string-to-pdf). I was telling him that he could *at least* make the effort of writing an actual question, writing it with a question mark as the formal language would tell us to do. He answered to me with:

> I posted exception and posting any exception in a question is a declarative statement of asking a answer that can resolve that.

Is there any place where this is written? Is this normal behavior, or was I right to ask him to formulate a question?

Comment: I agree with Servy's answer, but I also agree that the referenced question is unclear.

Comment: @Chicken Sure, but the point is that it's not unclear because it phrases the question as a problem statement rather than a question, it's unclear because it doesn't adequately explain what it's trying to do, and what the OP doesn't understand about the error or how to fix it.  It could be clarified without adding a grammatical question (by merely stating what they're trying to do more clearly, and what problems they're having trying to fix this error), and *isn't* going to be solved by adding a grammatical question that doesn't also contain that information (like, "how do I fix this?").

Comment: Yeah, I guess I poorly argumented on this one. Nice to see that each little mistake is an opportunity to grow in maturity, out there. But I was not sure about his statement, reputation can be intimidating out there, so I prefered to ask before stating anything. Thank you for this short, yet interesting explaination.

Answer (score 21):

Posting an exception message in a question is *not* an automatic declaration that you (the asker, not you Yassine) want help making the exception go away. Some exception messages are simply there to illustrate a flawed approach to a problem, and the focus of the question may not necessarily be on that flawed approach. As with any question, you need to actually describe the problem you want to solve and how that exception is getting in the way, if at all.

What it *is*, is an automatic invitation to scrutiny, especially if the message is self-explanatory and even tells you how to solve it. For example if an error message says that there's an unexpected `)` and tells you to remove it to fix the problem, and you tell us absolutely nothing about what you don't understand about the exception or how to resolve it, your question is going to get downvoted pretty quickly because the answer will seem blindingly obvious on the surface. Askers that have a habit of not reading error messages (which is a lot of people) tend to fall into this trap.

*That's* why a problem statement is important. It shows us that you made an attempt to understand the error and if there's something that's less obvious to you, readers might be willing to be a little more patient with you.

Answer (score 18):

> I posted exception and posting any exception in a question is a declarative statement of asking a answer that can resolve that.

No, I don't believe there is any place where this is written, and I don't think the SO community as a whole believes this. In practice it probably is rather common to just post a stack trace, but I wouldn't call it normal.

As Servy wrote, the important thing to consider is whether the question describes a problem to be solved. One can certainly do that without posting a grammatical question; posts do not *have* to contain a question mark.

However, personally, I *don't* think that just posting a stack trace qualifies as describing a problem to be solved.

Comment: "In practice it probably is rather common to just post a stack trace" -- perhaps this is common in some tags, but not in those I frequent.  I certainly agree that such a question does not qualify as describing a problem to be solved, which *itself* would not necessarily qualify as a suitable SO question.  I would almost certainly VTC a stack-trace-only question as "unclear what you're asking", and probably DV it as well.

Answer (score 14):

It's perfectly acceptable to post a question that doesn't contain a grammatical question, and instead described a problem that is to be solved.  If you are personally unclear as to what the problem is, or what exactly they're looking for in a solution (a problem that you could have whether their question is a grammatical question or not) then by all means indicate that you find the question unclear and try to help the author understand what you need to know or have clarified.

You're more than welcome to say that phrasing their problem as a question, rather than a problem statement, might make the question clearer to you (if you really think that would help) but if they feel that their problem is more clearly presented as a problem statement, rather than a question, there's no reason to tack on a "how do I fix this?" or some other such fluff on the end just so you can say that there's a question mark in the question.

Comment: Whereas I'll agree that it isn't a hard requirement that a SO question contain a grammatical question, I do think there's a positive correlation between questions' quality and whether they pose a grammatical question.  It comes down, I think, to whether the OP has put enough thought into it to determine with sufficient specificity what help or information they are actually trying to obtain.  Phrasing it as a problem statement instead of a question is not necessarily bad, but it is also not the usual way in which a question omits a grammatical question.